# What is the name of this type of vector product?

Tags: terminology, notation, linear-algebra

While formulating a certain algorithm, I have to describe the following operation between vectors.

Given $x, y \in \mathbb{R^d}$, the function $f(\cdot, \cdot): \mathbb{R^d} \times \mathbb{R^d} \to \mathbb{R^{d^2}}$ is defined as

$$f(x,y) = [x_1 y_1, x_1 y_2, \cdots, x_1 y_d, x_2 y_1, x_2 y_2, \cdots, x_d y_d]$$

As you can see this function is fairly similar to Cartesian product from set theory, which makes me think this might be a well-known operation with an specific name. Am I right?

I am aware that this operation can be achieved by allying matrix multiplication between a column-vector and a row-vector (i.e. $x^Ty$), but my operation needs to be generalizable to have more than two input vectors, e.g. $f(\cdot, \cdot, \cdot): \mathbb{R^d} \times \mathbb{R^d}\times\mathbb{R^d} \to \mathbb{R^{d^3}}$.

Comment: Lookup [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) or [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

Comment: @Lope I notice there are two terms at the end of the bracket $x_d$, $y_d$. Do you really mean to include those? In that case, it's not quite the standard outer/kronecker product suggested.

Comment: Those are not two terms, is the single term $x_d\cdot y_d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your direction question:

- In the two-dimensional case, you're looking for the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). The Euclidean inner product is $x^T y$ while the outer product is $xy^T$. The outer product generates a matrix.
- In the general case, you're asking for a [tensor
  product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).
- What you're asking for is also the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the vectors. (See Rodrigo de Azevedo's answer.)

#### Some programming comments:

- Be aware of [row major or column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), that is, how to handle multi-dimensional arrays.
- This is standard linear algebra, and I would recommend using linear algebra libraries if you're doing any medium to heavy lifting or if performance matters. Don't reinvent the wheel. Some [discussion is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959457/high-performance-c-multi-dimensional-arrays).

  - BLAS/[LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) are standard, stable, and fast. But calling BLAS/LAPACK functions is a pain.

Comment: Related? It *is* the Kronecker product.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Point taken. The qualifier "related" shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathrm x, \mathrm y \in \mathbb R^d$. The [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of these two $d$-dimensional column vectors is the following $d^2$-dimensional column vector

$$\mathrm x \otimes \mathrm y = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \mathrm y\\ x_2 \mathrm y\\ \vdots\\ x_d \mathrm y\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 y_1\\ x_1 y_2\\ \vdots\\ x_1 y_d\\ x_2 y_1\\ x_2 y_2\\ \vdots\\ x_2 y_d\\ \vdots\\ x_d y_1\\ x_d y_2\\ \vdots\\ x_d y_d\end{bmatrix}$$